# using session in MVC5 application best approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement session in asp.net mvc 5 application. The application does not have a login screen. The application checks if the user accessing the application exist in the database. The Active Director user name is captured in session and sent to the storedproc to verify of the user exist. If exist, I would need to store the Userprofile information in session.  I have created a repository class to access the data. I am calling the method from the session start method in global.asax. I would like to verify if my implementation is correct. How do  I update the session data if the information is changed.

**MCRHelper**

```
 public static string GetShortname()
        {
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            return username.Split('\\')[1];
        }
```

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
    public class UserProfileSessionData
    {
        public int UserProfileID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        public string DefaultLanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string DefaultCountryCode { get; set; }
        public int TimeZoneID { get; set; }
        public string TimeZoneName { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string NetworkID { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

**repository class**

```
public class SessionRespository
    {
        public List<UserProfileSessionData> GetUserProfileByNetworkId()
        {
            MCREntities db = new MCREntities();

            if (MCRHelper.UserValidate() == 1)
            {
                var userProfiles = db.spGetUserProfileByNetworkID(MCRHelper.GetShortname());
                return Mapper.Map<List<UserProfileSessionData>>(userProfiles);

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set SessionUtil.User here
            SessionRespository sessionRespository = new SessionRespository();
            Session["UserProfile"] = sessionRespository.GetUserProfileByNetworkId();
        }
```

Comment: No login screen... how do you get any information about the user? The data model shows: Forename, Surname, Emailadress... To update the data you could check if that data already exists in the Session object if so: update it and else create a new entry.

Comment: What does MCRHelper.GetShortname() do?

Comment: I have updated the post with the method. The just takes the ntlogon username from the string

Comment: Is this utilizing Windows Auth?

Comment: The userinformation is captured in the GetShortName method which uses   HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name which gets the identity of the current principal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to verify if my implementation is correct.

First of all, ***you should not store logged-in user's information in Session State*** not to mention using Session State is discouraged in ASP.NET MVC if possible.

*We used to store logged-in user information in Session State prior to ASP.NET Membership Provider which was 15 years ago.*

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC 5, you want to use ***ASP.NET OWIN Cookie Middleware***. Implementation is a lot easier than you think.

### [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs)

```
private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public void SignIn(User user)
{
    IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
    };

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
}

public void SignOut()
{
    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
}
```

## [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Startup.cs)

You also need to configure Startup for all those to happen.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplication.Startup))]
namespace YourApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can start using `[Authorize]` attribute in Controller and Action methods.

```
[Authorize]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

*Here is [my sample application at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin) which uses AD for Authentication. I have user friendly [login screen](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin#user-login), but you do not have use it if you do not want it.*

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why using session is bad as my application is going to run on a load balanced environment which takes care of session management . In my solution , I am reading userprofile information from the database and trying to store in session. How do I  store that information in cookie.

Comment: ***Http is state less***, and ASP.NET MVC tries to keep it that way, as we have so many issues with maintaining session states in ASP.NET Web Form. As I said, storing user information in session state is 15 years old method, and very fragile and hard to maintain, and we now have better solutions such as ***ASP.NET Identity*** and ***OWIN Middleware***. In addition, if you use Session State, you cannot take advantage of ASP.NET MVC's build in Authorize Attributes. If you later decide to migrate to ASP.NET Core, you can easily do so by using OWIN now.